# JFrame abrindo repetidamente duas vezes

Tags: java, swing, jframe

sou novo em programação para desktop, bom, estou fazendo um programa em java usando swing e banco de dados sqlite, já fiz algumas coisas funcionarem, porém após o login o jframe que deveria abrir uma unica vês abre duas vezes, alguém sabe como corrigir isto?

Segue o coidigo

```
 private void entrar() {

    String sql = "select * from login where usuario = ? and senha = ?";

    try {
        conn = conexao.ConnectionDB();         

        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, nomeUser.getText());
        pst.setString(2, senhaUser.getText());

        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()) {

           new TelaPrincipal().setVisible(true);
           this.dispose();

        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login inexistente");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

    }

}
```

Comment: Na sua classe TelaPrincipal, possui main?

Comment: Não, a minha main se encontra na tela de login.

Comment: Aparentemente no código que você adicionou na pergunta não há problemas, verique no seu construtor de TelaPrincipal se não há alguma chamada `setVisible(true)`. O problema parece não estar no código da pergunta.

Comment: vou caçar aqui, e dou uma resposta

Answer (score 1):

Olá, consegui resolver o problema, na verdade era um erro meu, acontece que eu tinha colocado o evento KeyPressed e o actionPerformade com o metodo entrar, porém de alguma forma, mesmo clicando com o mouse o KeyPressed ativava, basicamente retirei o KeyPressed e funcionou obrigado.